# PrestaShop as a webshop

Tags: web-hosting, prestashop

I have been asked by my friend who is starting a new webshop to find the best and cheapest way to get a webshop up and running.
Since my skills with php, html, css, mysql etc. are limited, and since I don't really know anything about security of webpages, I started looking for complete solutions.

There are a lot of companies selling webshops with domain and everything, but they are very expensive (about 40 euro a month) , and I'm sure that it can be done cheaper.

I looked at [PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/), and it looks quite good for a free webpage. This solution would only cost about 1 euro a month, which is a lot cheaper than a complete solution.

The thing is that I don't want responsibility if something goes wrong, and therefore I want to ask you Webmasters if you have any experience with PrestaShop?

- Is it secure to use for a small webshop?
- Does it need a lot maintenance?
- Compared to a ready made solution like [ScanNet](http://www.scannet.dk)    (Danish
  webshop hosting company), what are its weaknesses?
- What are your opinions and experiences?
- If I chose PrestaShop as a solution,  would it work well with www.one.com (using the 5Gb webhotel)?

I hope you can help me and I appreciate the time you took to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it secure to use for a small webshop?

Absolutely. There are thousands of sites using PrestaShop - the main consideration is to keep it updated as security updates are released. PrestaShop has documentation that makes the update process fairly easy.

> Does it need a lot maintenance?

It's not bad. The main trick here is in the configuration - you want to be sure you turn on caching and compiling, which will keep the site running fairly smooth.

> Compared to a ready made solution like ScanNet (Danish webshop hosting company), what are its weaknesses?

There will be a little more maintenance, but the benefit is you will be able to make it do whatever you want. When you host with a pre-built, hosted platform like ScanNet or Volusion, you are limited to the functionality the company has put into the software. With PrestaShop, you can install third-party themes and extensions to increase the functionality of the platform, or if you are so inclined and capable, you may code and implement your own extensions.

> What are your opinions and experiences?

I've used PrestaShop to build several sites and it's a decent platform, once you get past the learning curve. It's very flexible and one of the better open-source carts in my opinion.

> If I chose PrestaShop as a solution, would it work well with www.one.com (using the 5Gb webhotel)?

I can't speak to that specific plan, but any decent shared hosting plan that supports SSL should work.

Comment: I really appreciate someone that have experience with PrestoShop to answer my question!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I learned from my experience that it is not easy when you want to make a payment because Paypal module may charge you in some area.